# Typeorm - Create new table which is linked to users table via `userId` column

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have `users` entity and table and now, I want to create new table `user-settings` with two columns where first column should be `userId` and other column is `setting`. How to create new entity `user-settings-entity` for typeORM which will contain these two columns and be linked with users table via `userId`? So every user has corresponding record in `user-settings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `one-to-one` relations.

You can find the documentation here https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ManyToMany relationship.

Here is an example:

```
import { Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Setting)
  @JoinTable()
  settings: Setting[];
}

@Entity()
export class Setting {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}
```

If you want to have custom fields on the join table, you might need to create it as a separate entity then use `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany`.

More documentation: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations